# IOS RestKit infinite loop when I try to map and send a class "Customer" NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, restkit

I have a client class with persistent data from Facebook on core data and I want to send this by Restik mapped to the server class. But when I send using `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]` it gets into an infinite loop, does not return with an error. But if you add the url again

```
manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http:// ***"]];
[setRequestSerializationMIMEType manager: RKMIMETypeJSON];
```

and not use the `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]`

the server receives the request and returns all normal, but it also returns a warning: ***Asked to create an `object` RKManagedObjectRequestOperation, but managedObjectStore is nil.***

but it works, but I would use the url only once in the delegate and remove this message.

Class Client.m

```
#import "Client.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

@implementation Client

// We use @dynamic for the properties in Core Data
@dynamic clientID;
@dynamic fbID;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic last_name;
@dynamic email;
@dynamic gender;
@dynamic birthday;



        +(RKObjectMapping *)clientResponseMapping{

            RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
                [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{

                                                  @"fbID": @"fbID",
                                                  @"name": @"name",
                                                  @"last_name": @"last_name",
                                                  @"email": @"email",
                                                  @"gender": @"gender",
                                                  @"birthday" : @"birthday"
                                                  }];

           return mapping;

        }
}
```

method send to server:

```
-(void) sendServerClient{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
//    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    // We wish to generate parameters of the format:
    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[[Cliente clientResponseMapping] inverseMapping] objectClass:[Client class] rootKeyPath:@"client" method: RKRequestMethodPOST];

//    manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

    // Construct an object mapping for the response
    // We are expecting JSON in the format:
    RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [Datas datasMapping];

    // Construct a response descriptor that matches any URL (the pathPattern is nil), when the response payload
    // contains content nested under the `@"page"` key path, if the response status code is 200 (OK)
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"clients/create" keyPath:@"dados" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];


    // Register our descriptors with a manager
    RKObjectManager *manager =  [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://***"]];
    [manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
//    manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
//    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

//    NSError *error;
//    NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model.sqlite"];
//    NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
//    if (error) {
//        NSLog(@"unresolved error , ");
//        NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);
//        
//    }
//    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];


    [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


    // POST the parameterized representation of the `page` object to `/posts` and map the response
    [manager postObject:self.client path:@"clients/create" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) { ... }];
}
```

method viewDidLoad the same viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    managedObjectModel = [appDelegate managedObjectModel];
    managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    [appDelegate setupRestKit];
}
```

I have a method in AppDelegate to start restkit

```
-(void)setupRestKit{

    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_BASE]];

//    [[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key" value:@"your key"];
//    [[manager HTTPClient] setDefaultHeader:@"X-Parse-Application-Id" value:@"your key"];
    [manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    [RKObjectManager setSharedManager:manager];

    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
}
```

Does anyone know help me?

Comment: Where is the infinite loop? And why aren't you setting the `managedObjectStore`?

Comment: press pause when you are will be in infinity loop, and try look stack of calls. MB MOContext is lock?

Comment: sorry, I guess I did not express myself well, it's not an infinite loop is that I'm also using SVProgressHUD at the beginning of the method I use `[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:]; maskType: SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];` within the block and return the `[manager postObject: path : parameters: success:]`, I close with `[SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:]`, except that there is no return for the block failure nor success in

Comment: then my app crashes. ManagedObjectStore not used because the client property is estanciada, so I figured I did not need, but when the step he managedObjectStore the same error when I'm using the manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL: `[NSURL URLWithString: @ "http:// ..." ]]`